# Role-based access control with Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, zope, rbac

I am considering using Pyramid to build a middle sized web application. I would need to implement [RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control). What would be the best choice? Would it be possible to use Zope components?

Comment: My goal in implementing RBAC in the application is to be able to delegate some power to the user, meaning that a user could authorize another user to whatever action is available. Rbac also allows role hierarchy which is a very powerfull concept. I have not find any python modules that could help...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Pyramid but I use the following library in my flask project: https://github.com/muratgozel/py-rbac

Answer (score 3):

Well Pyramid implements an ACL authorization policy which maps principals to permissions.

1. Principals are configurable by you to mean whatever you like and are derived from the request (user) itself.
2. A permission is a string attached to an individual view or "operation".

Maybe I'm wrong, but RBAC seems to fit pretty naturally into this idea. I understand that RBAC tends to be more of a global policy whereas ACLs are generally contextual and thus attached to the data. This isn't really a problem though and depends on how you plan to structure the rest of your application.

You could also fairly simply implement your own `RBACAuthorizationPolicy`. In Pyramid it will be passed the principals and the permission and from there you could query your access mappings to determine whether to return an `Allowed` or `Denied` value for that user.

Comment: I found python acl which includes roles. https://github.com/limscoder/Python-ACL/ and https://github.com/kyleterry/simpleacl-py